# PowerShell Programming: Traverse folders and subfolders and apply pdftotext. I/O Error

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell-5.0

I have correctly written the following PowerShell command to traverse every folder and subfolder of a directory and display the contents of each such folders:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\whiskey\Tango\Charlie" –Recurse
```

I have also written a PowerShell script that correctly works and can extract text from each pdf file in a single folder.

```
cd "C:\whiskey"
$FILES= ls *.pdf
foreach ($f in $FILES) {
  & "C:\Program Files\xpdf-tools-win-4.02\bin32\pdftotext.exe" -enc UTF-8 "$f"
}
```

I am trying to combine both scripts in order to traverse all folders and subfolders and execute the pdftotext program. And so I wrote:

```
$files=Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\whiskey\Tango\Charlie" –Recurse
foreach ($f in $files){
    & "C:\Program Files\xpdf-tools-win-4.02\bin32\pdftotext.exe" -enc UTF-8 "$f"
}
```

; which is incorrect. I receive the following error: ***pdftotext.exe : I/O Error: Couldn't open file***. Note none of the pdf files are protected.

> **Question**: How do I correct this error?

Comment: $Files should be an array of FileSystemInfo objects (FileInfo, DirectoryInfo). try using $f.FullName to get the full path of the file as a string or $f.Name if you just want the shortname.

Comment: @FrankThomas something along the lines of $files=@(Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users\ahernandez\Desktop\BW\OCR\Mallinckrodt" –Recurse ) ?

Comment: based on what I'm seeing here https://stackoverflow.com/a/32915159/1624069 , I don't think that will work. the issue isn't the array, the issue is that the things in the array are not strings. I suggest that in your last line, you change "$f" to "$f.FullName" or "$f.tostring()".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This NOT an answer but an extended comment following @FrankThomas. It would appear the following script "works"

```
$FOLDERS=@(Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\whiskey\Tango\Charlie" –Recurse)
$FOLDERS #print contents of array
foreach ($f in $FOLDERS) {
  & "C:\Program Files\xpdf-tools-win-4.02\bin32\pdftotext.exe" -enc UTF-8 $f.FullName
}
```

Indeed it goes through each folder and subfolder and executes the pdftotext program and so correctly extracts the contents of the pdf file into a text file. However I still have an error message:
**pdftotext.exe : I/O Error: Couldn't open file "C:\whiskey\Tango\Charlie"**. I suspect the name of every folder was saved in the array $FOLDERS. Subsequently PowerShell passes the name of the folder   to pdftotext; which will error since it cannot find a .pdf extension.

---

The following is the correct PS script:

```
$FOLDERS=@(Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\whiskey\Tango\Charlie" –Recurse -Filter *.pdf)
$FOLDERS #print contents of every folder
foreach ($f in $FOLDERS) {
  & "C:\Program Files\xpdf-tools-win-4.02\bin32\pdftotext.exe" -enc UTF-8 $f.FullName
}
```

I need to filter for just pdf files.

Comment: ok, so thats because you are processing a directory. I recommend you change your first line to set the path to `C:\whiskey\Tango\Charlie\*.pdf` as shown in example 3 here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7.1  That should prevent you from processing directories or non-pdf files.